# Codeigniter data from view to controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, module

New to Codeigniter and trying to teach myself by exploring and messing with InvoicePlane however i'm a bit stuck when it comes to this section.

I've got a controller which loops through a number of different styles. To sends it to index.php view and is displayed fine.

Each style might have a parent style and again I can display the parent style ID fine but i'm trying to get my head around how to get the name of each parent style from the ID.

For example, the view page is as follows:-

```
            <?php foreach ($property_styles as $style) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $style->property_style_id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($style->property_style_group) ? lang('yes') : lang('no'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $style_parent->property_style_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $style->property_style_name; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('property_styles/form/' . $style->property_style_id); ?>"
                       title="<?php echo lang('edit'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit orange fa-margin"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

The third table cell hows - $style_parent->property_style_name which is where i'd like the name to appear. The value it needs to use to determine is $style->property_style_parent_id

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you are doing your query to fetch property styles you should also fetch the `property_style_parent_name` as well with your `property_style_parent_id`. Then you can refer to it in your view with $style->property_style_parent_name` (or whatever its property name is)

Comment: and if I wanted to do say two loops, one for the parents and then one for the sub items, how would that be possible?

Comment: That depends on the way your data is structured. Can't give you an effective way without an example on your real data.